# Log in and password using VB6 and Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-office, connection-string

I'm trying to create a VB6 application linking to Microsoft Access 2007. I'm going to save account names and passwords in Access 2007. I'm using VB6 as the front end. Would somebody help me on the connection string and the codes to store and check the account names and passwords.

Comment: post what you have done and then we can help you

Comment: is this correct?

Set cnct = New ADODB.Connection
Set rcrd = New ADODB.Recordset

cnct.ConnectionString = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Account.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
cnct.Open

rcrd.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rcrd.CursorType = adOpenKeyset

rcrd.Open "select * from TblAccount", cnct, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this link

[login form connecting to ms access](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Visual-Basic-1048/login-form-connecting-ms.htm)

EDIT

Then how about

[Asking for code design advice: working with VB.Net and Ms-Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251459/asking-for-code-design-advice-working-with-vb-net-and-ms-access)

should help as well.

Comment: sir, im using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as a provider